# Oracle 10g On Windows Hard-Disk Crash

Tags: restore, oracle-10g

We had a hard-disk crash of our legacy application on Oracle 10g database server. We were later able to recover all the files in oradata directory. We do not have any recent export files. I had reinstalled Oracle and made efforts to use the files from the old oradata files. This has not worked. Please any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

split your recovery to steps so we know where it breaks.

1 Create instance using old parameter file. Are you able to start idle instance?

2 Copy control files to locations from step 1. Try to mount the database

3 Copy datafiles and try to open the database.

The process could fail on every step

Comment: I am very thankful for your response. I will try these out and give a feedback.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that you can just replace files.  You need a proper backup.  It looks like you don't have one.  The next best thing to try is to replace the files and then try to run a database repair.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. How do I replace the files, please?